# spatie error : PermissionServiceProvider Not Loaded (Laravel Permissions)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-permission

i am using [Laravel Permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction) By spatie.
i had done same as provided in document for using Laravel permissions.

In `app.php` i had added the `Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,` at bottom of the array

and done all things that mentioned in the documentation.my laravel version is `7.x`

```
//My Route.php
Route::get('/createRole',function(){

    $role = Role::find(1);
    $permission = Permission::find(1);
    $role->givePermissionTo($permission);
    return "Roles Added Success";

});
```

And my O/P Says

> Class 'Role' not found

Comment: the provider is not `'PermissionServiceProvider'` it is `'Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider'`

Comment: Updated answer @lagbox

Comment: Did you import both classes? `use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;` and `use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;`

Comment: No. Thank you for your help @lagbox & Remul

Answer (score 0):

This because actual provider name is "Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider".
Also, generally, you don't need register it manually, only if you disable automate package discovery.